# Prove that $\mathbb{R^*}$, the set of all real numbers except $0$, is not a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Prove that $\mathbb{R^*}$ is not a cyclic group. (Here $\mathbb{R^*}$ means all the elements of $\mathbb{R}$ except $0$.)

I know from the definition of a cyclic group that a group is cyclic if it is generated by a single element. I was thinking of doing a proof by contradiction but then that ended up nowhere.

Comment: Hint: can $-1$ be any power of another real number?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbb{R}^*$ is cyclic.
Let $a$ be its generator.
Since $-1 \in \mathbb{R}^*$, there exists a nonzero integer $n$ such that $-1 = a^n$.
Then $a^{2n} = 1$.
Hence the order of $a$ is finite.
This is a contradiction.

Comment: $a^{2n}=1$ does not imply $2n=0$. for example $a=1,2n=10$. though in general this proof is correct since you deduce $a=-1$ from $a^n=-1$

Comment: @Belgi If $a^{2n} = 1$ for some $n \neq 0$, $\mathbb{R}^*$ must be finite.

Comment: As I said, this also leads to a contradiction (in more way the one), so the conclusion is correct but the argument is not

Comment: @Belgi Please explain why my argument is not correct.

Comment: @Belgi Please explain your objection. This appears correct to me.

Comment: After the edit it is correct, I objected to the $2n=0$ part that seemed to be concluded only since $a^{2n}=1$

Comment: @Belgi The edited proof is essentially the same as the original. I just simplified the proof. Please explain why $2n=0$ cannot be concluded from $a^{2n}=1$.

Comment: @Belgi You seem to forget that $a$ is a generator of $\mathbb{R}^*$. It's not just an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{R}^*$. So $a^{2n} = 1$ implies $2n = 0$. Hope this helps.

Comment: it only implie that the order of the element divides $2n$, you have to mention the group is infinite otherwise the contradiction won't be $-1=1$ as written

Comment: I agree with the edited version. I just wanted to say that without saying that otherwise the group would of been finite you can't deduce straight out that $2n=0$. thank you

Comment: @Belgi The original version is correct. If $2n \neq 0$, the order of $a$ is finite. Since $a$ generates $\mathbb{R}^*$, this is impossible. Hope this helps. Or are you saying we should not skip an argument which is easy enough?

Comment: Yes, I just meant this argument should be inserted in the proof

Comment: @Belgi I think it's easy to see that $2n = 0$ follows from $a^{2n} = 1$.
You just don't think so. In that case, you can ask me.
But that does not mean my original proof was not correct.

Comment: If you wonder, I already upvoted ;)

Answer (score 29):

**HINT** 
$\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable

Comment: That's the extreme answer, but there are more algebraic answers that also let you show that for any sub-field of the reals the non-zeros are not cyclic...

Comment: If future readers are puzzled by the hint: every cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z_n}$

Answer (score 4):

clark's answer is surely a great and simple one.  Thomas Andrews' hint is another great one.  Here's a more complicated answer that shows more, that there are entire intervals of numbers that would not be generated.

Let $x$ be a generator of the cyclic group $\mathbb{R}^*$.  If $|x| = 1$, then all powers of $x$ satisfy $|x^n| = 1$.  So, $|x| < 1$ or $|x| > 1$.

If $|x| < 1$, then $|x^{-1}| > 1$ and $x^{-1}$ is also a generator.  So, assume $|x| > 1$.

If $|x| > 1$, then $|x| = 1 + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.  Any positive power of $x$ will satisfy $|x|^n = (1 + \epsilon)^n > 1 + \epsilon$.  Any negative power of $x$ will satisfy $|x|^{-n} = (1 + \epsilon)^{-n} < (1+ \epsilon)^{-1}$.

So, there are entire intervals that are never achieved.

Comment: I upvoted. Can you please flesh out where the last sentence came from?

Answer (score 4):

Say $g$ is the generator. It must be negative. Either $g<-1, g=-1, $ or $g>-1$.  $g=-1$ clearly does not work.  Let $h = \frac12(-1 + g)$.  $h$ lies strictly between $g$ and $-1$. How is $h$ generated?

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{R}^*$ has infinite order. If it were cyclic, it would have to contain an element that does not have a cube root.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g\in\mathbb R^*$ and $G=\langle g \rangle=\{ g^n : n \in \mathbb Z\}$.

If $|g|=1$ then $G \subseteq \{ \pm 1 \} \neq \mathbb R^*$.

Otherwise, we may assume that $|g|>1$.

If $g>1$ then $x=(g+1)/2 \notin G$ because $1 < x < g$.

If $g<-1$ then $x=(g-1)/2 \notin G$ because $g < x < -1$.

In both cases, we have $G\neq \mathbb R^*$.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to see it: Assume $\Bbb{R}$ is cyclic and $a$ is its generator. Then $1=na$ for some $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ and $\sqrt{2}=ma$ for some $m\in\Bbb{Z}$. These imply that $a=1/n=\sqrt{2}/m$ and hence $\sqrt{2}=n/m$, contradiction.

Comment: The question is about the multiplicative group $\mathbb R^*=\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, not the additive group $\mathbb R$.