# $\mathbb{R}^*$ not cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to show that the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}^*$ of non-zero real numbers is not cyclic.

This is what I'm thinking. I need to show that there exists no $a$ such that all elements of $\mathbb{R}^*$ are of the form $a^n$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. But I'm not sure how to do this. Should I provide a counter-example by choosing two real numbers and showing that they cannot be of the form $a^n$ with the same base?

Comment: Hint: Countability.

Comment: Suppose you got a generator $g$. What is $g/2$ in terms of $g^k$?

Comment: Possible dublicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204579/prove-that-mathbbr-the-set-of-all-real-numbers-except-0-is-not-a-cycl/204580#204580

Comment: @GabrielR.: Well, if g happens to be $\sqrt{2}$, then $g/2 = g^{-1}$. :)

Comment: @jpvee which is obviously not a generator ;)

Comment: @GabrielR. Yes, you are right, but then every real is obviously not a generator...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint for a quick proof: every cyclic group is countable.

Comment: .. or finite, in case one doesn't consider finite sets to be "countable".

Comment: +1, but I never understood how a finite set could not be countable.

Comment: @MartinArgerami There are finite numbers so big I feel unable to count so far :)

Comment: @hagen: fine, but you still probably claim that the (infinite) set of all those numbers is "countable" ;)

Answer (score 7):

It has an element of order 2, but isn't finite.

Comment: I like that one.

Answer (score 1):

Analogous question for $R^+$:

You can assume that $a>1$ (otherwise work with $a^{-1}$, also a generator). Then any point between $a$ and $a^2$ cannot be a power of $a$. (All the negative powers are $<1$, and all the other positive powers are $>a^2$.)