# Examples of cyclic groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I'm currently reading through "A Book of Abstract Algebra" - C Pinter and have come across cyclic groups $$G = \langle a \rangle = \{ e, a_1, \ldots, a_n \}$$

Are there any cyclic groups isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: By R, do you mean the real numbers? Notice that the real numbers are not a cyclic group...

Comment: For the assertion that real numbers are not a cyclic group, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204579/prove-that-mathbbr-the-set-of-all-real-numbers-except-0-is-not-a-cycl)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I did but J. W. Tanner I think has answered my question, thank you though

Comment: Alternative: a cyclic group has at most countably many elements, but $\mathbb{R}$ has uncountably many.

Comment: Here's something to keep in mind: being cyclic is an isomorphism invariant, meaning that that if $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic groups, and if $G$ is cyclic, then $H$ is cyclic. So, your question is equivalent to asking "Is $\mathbb R$ cyclic?", and the answer is "No".

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you, I realised after the first few comments that every cyclic group is isomorphic to some $Z_n$ if finite or $Z$ if infinite and there is no isomorphism from $Z$ to $R$, so we can't have an isomorphism from a cyclic group to $R$. Thank you for the other viewpoint though!

Answer (score 2):

Every cyclic group is countable. The group of real numbers under addition is uncountable. Therefore, the group of real numbers is not cyclic.